# VB: Editing graphics of picturebox

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010

I have a picturebox called "imagebox" which has an image loaded into it via a filebrowserdialog. I have another picturebox which loads the image of the first picturebox into it and that one is called "canvasbox". (By clicking the first picturebox, it loads the image into the second picturebox.)
The second picturebox will be where I draw on the image and make changes to it before rendering a final image. My question is, how would I make the second picturebox a zoomed in version? I mean to where you can see the pixels in a grid like in Paint.Net? Because the first picturebox will always be a small resolution of 32x32 or 64x32, etc so I am trying to make it to where in the second picturebox, you can use a pencil tool and pencil in the pixels precisely where you want them. I want this picturebox to automatically be zoomed in. No scroll wheel zoom or anything. Lets say, I will zoom in at a fixed percentage or something. Enough to where you can easily see the pixel grid. but I need the changes to show up in real time in the first picturebox as I am editing it to see what it looks like in its original size as I edit it in the zoomed size. Later, when I render it, it will be rendered in the same format it started in the first picturebox. I hope I am explaining this well enough. I dont have any code on this because I absolutely have no idea where to begin on something like this.

Comment: Did you consider painting zoomed picturebox by yourself? (Including calculation according to zoom setting etc.) So for 200% zoom, paint every pixel of original image as 2×2 pixels of zoomed image. Another workaround is available but limited: picturebox allows image stretching trough certain properties.

Comment: actually i think i might have figured it out with the interpolationmode thing.

Comment: Yes. If you need only trivial functionality, interpolation mode can suffice. Beyond basic needs, you might need going on your own.